# Jsch Java progam to pass arguements to a linux process

Tags: java, linux, jsch

I have a binary executable file named as "datasimulator" that runs in a remote linux machine which starts an interactive process where a user can provide input and get its corresponding output like below -

```
[root@host]$ ./datasimulator 
> set country USA    //user passing this command 
Country set to USA   //response from process  
> set country Canada  
Country set to Canada  
>exit  
Thank you for using datasimulator.  
[root@host]$
```

I am trying to automate this process using java jsch utility where through my java program I can pass input and get the output back to my program. Though I am able to start the datasimulator through jsch ssh connection but not able to pass input to this simulator process. Kindly help. 
Below is the java program which I am trying to use -

> ```
> JSch jsch = new JSch(); session = jsch.getSession(username, host, 22);
> session.setPassword(password);
> java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
> config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
> session.setConfig(config);
> session.connect();
>
> channel=session.openChannel("shell");
> OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
> ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);
> channel.connect();
> ps.println("cd /path/To/datasimulator/ && ./datasimulator");
> ps.println("Country set to USA");
> Thread.sleep(5000);
> ps.println("Country set to Canada");
> Thread.sleep(5000);
> ps.close();
> channel.disconnect();
> session.disconnect();
> ```

This program starts the datasimulator but not able to execute next consecutive commands successfully.

Comment: Please post your java code,  without it it's hard to tell what you did wrong

Comment: I have updated the post with java code.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/6415810/180100 could help you

Comment: "ps.println("Country set to USA");" Shouldn't this be `ps.println("set country USA");` ?